# WPF how to get selected file from OpenFileDIalog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am new to WPF, I checked around for solutions to my question but I haven't quite found the right way to do things. I am making an application where the user can make an account and add a profile image. So in the `Create_Account_Page` I have a button that on click has an event to create a `OpenFileDialog` and then call `dialog.showdialog()`;

What I want is to be able to get the selected file and save it to my project folder. I know that there is a `FileOk` event and it seems its what I need but all the solutions I've found don't work.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The question posed is a duplicate but it ended up being a reference issue. where my project needed to add a ref to system.windows.form.

To any one reading this, theres an OpenFileDialog in System.Windows.Forms and one in system.Win32 dont mix the two!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
var newDestination = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    var fullPath = dialog.FileName;
    var fileOnlyName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
    File.Copy(fullPath, Path.Combine(newDestination, fileOnlyName));
}
```

Comment: `if (dialog.ShowDialog())` should be all you need

Comment: @FrankerZ `ShowDialog` return Nullable<bool> (bool?). so cant.

Comment: what i have seen online everyone is doing dialog.showdialog() == DialogResult.OK but that isnt working for me

Comment: @Alvaromon this in case `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`. my code demostration `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` but besides, everything is the same

Comment: @lomed thank you this helped me im new to WPF so i didnt realize that my project didnt have a reference to System.Windows.Forms